# Mongrel::DirHandler equivalent for Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, mongrel

I'm using Mongrel::DirHandler to control response headers for static files - this works great on my dev machine. My production machine uses Passenger so my headers aren't getting set. How do I control headers for static files when using Passenger?

snippet from my environment.rb:

```
if defined? Mongrel::DirHandler
  module Mongrel
    class DirHandler
      def send_file_with_expires(req_path, request, response, header_only=false)

        if req_path =~ /((\/images)|javascripts|stylesheets)/
          response.header['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=315360000'
          response.header['Expires'] = (Time.now + 10.years).rfc2822
        else
          response.header["Last-Modified"] = Time.now.httpdate
          response.header["Expires"] = 0
          # HTTP 1.0
          response.header["Pragma"] = 'no-cache'
          # HTTP 1.1 ‘pre-check=0, post-check=0′ (IE specific)
          response.header["Cache-Control"] = 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, pre-check=0, post-check=0'
        end

        send_file_without_expires(req_path, request, response, header_only)
      end
      alias_method :send_file_without_expires, :send_file
      alias_method :send_file, :send_file_with_expires
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Passenger, I assume you're under apache, so your request isn't going through Mongrel anymore. If so, you can establish rules on the `.htaccess` file inside the `public` directory of your application.

[Here's an explination on how to do it.](http://forum.powweb.com/showthread.php?t=70536)