# Installing Ruby on Rails for Windows 7 (up to date)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, installation

I'm a designer and not a coder and having issues with the first install.

I downloaded Rails 1.8.6 and Instant Rails.

I opened a console and tried updating gems. Nothing worked there.

I think I will just delete everything and start over because I'm sure I broke something by now. I was really thinking about buying a Mac today just to get it working.

What do you recommend for:
1. What EXACTLY to download?
2. Steps to take?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been developing with Rails on Windows 7 for over a year and have never experienced any frustrations due to this. [These instructions](http://rubyonrails.org/download) have always worked perfectly for me.

Download and install Ruby 1.8.7

http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/71492/rubyinstaller-1.8.7-p299.exe

Download the latest RubyGems, and extract the file somewhere

http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126

Open the command prompt, cd into the directory you extracted RubyGems too, and do "ruby setub.rb"

On the command line anywhere run "gem install rails"

I have no idea why so many people are anti Rails/Windows. I suppose OS X is easier since it comes with Rails already installed. Linux on the other hand you can easily jack up your environment if you mix up using apt-get and gems to install libraries.

Comment: +1 You're a more patient man than me. Which DBMS are you using for development on Windows?

Comment: I'm currently using mysql, although I've been meaning to move over to sqlite for a while - I just had mysql already installed and squirrel sql configured to use it.

Comment: Ok this is what I don't understand. I can get the Rails to show up in my localhost with "Welcome aboard". Does that mean it's installed? I can't seem to get any editors to produce any results though. I'm using Simply Rails 2 book as a programming and installing guide.

When you say command prompt are you talking about the console? I have Mongrel 1.1.2 running right now and not sure how to get back to the prompt to type. Sorry I'm a beginner on code (I do use PHP and CSS on design though).

Comment: Oh, and I found this link - http://blog.code71.com/2010/03/ruby-on-rails-setup-on-windows.html but I don't even know what #2 is - PATH? Is that the folder path? How do I type that and where (int he console?).

Comment: Yeah, click the Windows button and type in 'cmd' - that's the command prompt I'm talking about.

And if you see that message then Rails is in fact installed, and you have successfully created a rails app. What do you mean about getting editors to produce results?

Comment: Using RadRails I get "Empty external server URL" when trying to open a page called 01-car-classes.rb - What does that mean?

Comment: PATH is an environment variable, I believe when you use the ruby executable to install ruby there was an option to add ruby to your path - I'm not sure if you chose to do that or not.

You can add things to your path by clicking the windows button, right clicking my computer -> properties -> advanced system settings -> environment variables

Comment: Ah, I have no idea, I don't use RadRails. I just use a regular text editor: e - texteditor.

Comment: Thanks for helping. When I type gem install rails in the console I get:
ERROR: While executing gem <Gem::RemoteSourceException>
HTTP Response 301 fetching http://gems.rubyforge.org/yaml

Comment: Are you for sure using the latest version of rubygems: 1.3.7?

Comment: I doubt it. I'm searching how I find out what version I have now.

Comment: Where do I download the 1.3.7 to? Inside the Ruby\bin folder?

Comment: It doesn't matter, when you run setup.rb it will setup things correctly.

Comment: I tried doing this "ruby setub.rb" as you mentioned above but it says no such file or directory -- setub.rb <LoadError>

It appears it might have something to do with my InstantRails but I could be wrong.

Comment: I did "gem install rails" and 8 gems were installed! Now it's installing ri docs

Comment: yeah, that's what it should do. The docs may take a while. I've actually never heard of InstantRails, so I'm not sure what it could have done.

Comment: I fixed my paths to everything too. I was over complicating it. It's similar to old DOS. lol Back on the right path! :) I did get the 1.3.7 gems to install. I had 1.0.1 installed. I'm installing another round of rails too up to 1.8.7 from 1.8.6 I believe. Thanks again for your help! - Ken

Comment: I did a NEW, clean install based off your recommendations. How do I tie in the db now? I downloaded sqlite3 but not sure how to get it running and I read the sqlite3 site and about 40 forums and 3 sites and nothing explainable.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I'd almost just download VirtualBox and install Ubuntu in it, then develop with Rails on there. Things just work better on *nix systems when it comes to Ruby/Rails/gems/etc. Rails development on Windows is more pain than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

Cody's right, but I have more to say than will fit in a comment.

Rails on Windows just pain. You don't have to buy a shiny new Mac (I do like my Mac though). I happen to prefer developing Rails apps on Ubuntu. If you do Rails development for any extended period of time you'll probably want to move to [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/). Passenger doesn't run on Windows.

My day job is writing .net code and while Mono is great, I wouldn't develop an application targeting a Windows OS on an OS X or Linux machine. I'm not a fanboy by any means - when I decide to take on a new language or framework, I do some research and find out the best platform to use. I don't want to sit and fight with Ruby or Rails because Windows isn't well supported - I'll just go with a *nix based machine and be on my way. When in Rome...

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you move to Passenger on the machine you are developing on?

Comment: I was just glad to see no one mentioned me being a "designer" and having a PC anyway. :)

Comment: Because when you don't develop on the same platform that you deploy on you ask silly questions on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230534/mongreldirhandler-equivalent-for-passenger

Comment: I suppose so, but I'd still rather opt for more lightweight tools for development.

Comment: nginx is pretty light. You can also produce url's that are closer to a production environment... subdomains with the correct amount of "parts", no ports - stuff like that. If you like developing Rails apps on Windows, right on; just not my thing.

Comment: Looks like I got it. Thanks everyone for your help! :) (and patience)